# How to remove duplicates within the key of an array

Tags: php, arrays, key

Im making a php site and i'm trying to get rid of all duplicate values within the key array. So if i have for example 2 twice in the key array how would i remove one of them.

My array looks like this:

```
Array
{
    [class 1] => Array
      {
           [0] => 1
           [1] => 2
           [2] => 3
           [3] => 2
      }


    [class 2] => Array
      {
           [0] => 1
           [1] => 2
           [2] => 3
           [3] => 2
      }
}
```

and i want to remove the duplicates that occur throughout the entire array.

```
Array
{
    [class 1] => Array
      {
           [0] => 1
           [1] => 2
           [2] => 3
      }


    [class 2] => Array
      {
           [0] => 1
           [1] => 2
           [2] => 3
      }
}
```

I've had a look online but I can only find examples of how to remove duplicate keys. Perhaps this could be done with a foreach loop but im not sure.
All help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: the built-in functions won't do this. you'll have to loop on the main array, and do a `array_unique()` on each of the child arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `array_map` to execute `array_unique` on each sub-array of the array:

```
$array = array_map('array_unique', $array);
```

Not necessary, but if you want to reorder the keys afterward then use `array_values` the same way:

```
$array = array_map('array_values', $array);
```